# Find n and m such that $n²-m²=28$

Tags: number-theory

Find the integers $n$ and $m$ that satisfy this equation:

$$ n^2-m^2=28 $$

I tried to use ideas of diophantine equations, but it goes to something too complicated for something found in a textbook.

Comment: Is "sth" supposed to mean "something"? Regardless, the left side factors nicely....

Answer (score 1):

$28
= n^2-m^2
= (n-m)(n+m)
$.

Now,
look at the factors of 28
and determine
n and m from them.

Remember that
n and m can be negative.

Comment: Thanks your approach helped alot

Comment: Then please accept it.